# Changing the statusbar color in Delphi

Tags: delphi, statusbar

This can be achieved by setting PanelStyle to psDrawMode and in OnDrawPanel event of the statusbar, a code will be something like this:

```
StatusBar.Canvas.Brush.Color = clBlue;  // any color
StatusBar.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
// more code e.g. write text to panel
```

However the border color of the statusbar remains the same and very noticeable even if the border width is set to 0.  Is there a way how to change the color of the entire statusbar including borders?  TIA.

Comment: I'm afraid, no. Not if you want to keep Windows themeing. If you can disable Windows themeing (project - options - application - runtime themes) you can set the Color property to the same color as you paint the panels, and it will work almost as you wish. The border shades are still visible, and the resize grip down right remained gray at first but suddenly changed to the color in `Color`.

Comment: Well, you could disable themes for that one control. Using SetWindowTheme.

Comment: Sirs, thank you for the response.